# dynamic_cast<sibling*>(this) fails in destructor

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, mixins, virtual-destructor

I'm writting a set of mix-in classes (Pre and Post) and no, I can't use virtual inheritance. Pre sets things up in the constructor before Main::Main() and Post cleans things up in the destructor befor Main::~Main():

```
class Post {
  public:
    virtual ~Post() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%p->%s\n", this, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    Main *m = dynamic_cast<Main *>(this);
    assert(m != nullptr);
};
class Mixed : public Pre, public Main, public Post { };
```

But when Mixed::~Mixed() gets called it calls Post::~Post and the assertion fails. Why is that and how can I make a mix-in class that can do some cleanup before Main::~Main() gets called?

Note: I could store a pointer to Main in the Post class but that seems stupid.

Comment: Why can't you use a virtual destructor? You could just put the relevant code in the destructor for the `Mixed` class.

Comment: What do `Pre` and `Post` do?  Do they modify the state of `Main` or do they have there on state to manage?  If you are in the destructor for `Post` then `*this` is a `Post` not a `Main`.

Comment: When the `Post` subobject is being destroyed, `this` really is only that subobject; the `Mixed` that inherited it does not exist any more. (Mixin classes that rely on being mixed-in in conjunction with some other class don't sound very useful. Mixins are usually designed to be independent.)

Comment: @owacoder That is a virtual destructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, Pre and Post modify state.

Comment: As for a solution to your problem: maybe instead of `Post` having a destructor, it could just have a static function called `destroy` that accepts a `Main*` as a parameter. Then make `Main` into a class template that takes a parameter (call it `D` for destroy) to tell it how to clean itself up, and calls `D::destroy(this)` first thing in its own destructor. A simple "policy". I don't really know whether this is what you want, though. You'd end up with `class Mixed: public Main<Pre,Post> {` or similar.

Comment: @molbdnilo,@owacoder There is a chain of classes starting at Main and the mixins work for any class derived from Main. The classes are extern to my source so I can't fix them for virtual inheritance and have to mixin my Pre/Post to every derived class.

Comment: @SteveJessop The class (as `Main*`) gets destroyed outside of my source with `delete p;` I think the virtual destructor is the only way to hook a mixin into that. Main is outside my source so can't change that.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: OK, since if you can't change `Main` you can inherit from it: `class Mixed : public MixHelper<Pre,Main,Post> {`, and then `template <typename Pre, typename Main, typename Post> class MixHelper : public Main { ~MixHelper() { Post::destroy(this) } };`. You need `Main::~Main` to be virtual already, otherwise it's never going to be valid for a derived class of it to be deleted in code you don't control using a `Main*`.

Comment: Oh, but of course there's no way that can arrange for `Pre` to set things up in the constructor before the `Main` constructor is called. Hmm. So keep `Pre` out of `MixHelper`. `Pre` can't modify any state of `Main` anyway if it's called before `Main::Main`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Didn't you mean `class MixHelper : public Pre, public Main, public Post { ... }`? The mixins need  access to Main. But with the MixHelper class I actually don't need Post since that only has the destructor. `Pre::preMainDestructor(this);` will do just fine. I think I will go with `using MixedBase = Mixer<Mixin, Base>; using MixedDerived1 = Mixer<Mixin, Derived1>; using MixedDerived2 = Mixer<Mixin, Derived2>; ...`